# What does Drools do with ambiguous matches?

Tags: drools, rule-engine

I'm playing around with some rules to standardize street addresses that failed look-up from a service provider.

I've defined this rule

```
rule "Derive Street Aliases"
when
    $street     : Street();
then
    insert( new StreetAlias($street.getPrefixPart() + " " + $street.getStemmedPart(), $street.getName()) );
end
```

It takes a street name like "South Main Street" and creates the alias "South Main".

This other rule then picks up the alias:

```
rule "Street Alias Match"
when
  $userAddress : UserAddress();
  $streetAlias : StreetAlias(alias == $userAddress.getStreetPart());
then  
  $userAddress.setResolvedAddress($userAddress.getNumberPart() + " " + $streetAlias.getName());
end
```

This would work fine until a "South Main Avenue" is inserted. Then the alias "South Main" would become ambiguous.

What then is supposed to happen in the 2nd rule? Would it detect a conflict? Would it fire twice so that the last one wins?

I'm interested in the theory of what should happen, as I'm fairly new to Rules Engines.

Answer (score 0):

It is the fundamental principle of the [many pattern/many object pattern match problem](https://synrc.com/publications/workflow/rules/RETE%20Match%20Algorithm%20-%20Forgy%20OCR.pdf) that the engine should produce *all possible matches*. In rule based system this means that the engine must explore all possible combinations while evaluate constraints and create *activations* for each rule, combining facts in various tuples, which will then be used in rule firing.

If you have addresses stored as

```
class Address {
    String streetSpecific;
    String streetGeneric;
}
```

the same "specific" part can be used with several generic parts even in the same city. (Although, duplication of the full street name also occurs.) With an alias

```
class Alias {
    String specific;
}
```

this rule finds all possible matches

```
rule "find possibles"
when
    Alias( $spec: specific )
    Address( streetSpecific == $spec )
then
    // another possible match
end
```

and the rule

```
rule "find similar"
when
    $a1: Address( $spec: streetSpecific  )
    $a2: Address( this != $a1, streetSpecific == $spec )
then
    // display similar pair
end
```

will find "similar" street names (but note that this rule will fire too often - can you see why?)

Note that even the full name is no guarantee for uniqueness within a single city...